# Bootstrap navbar collapse doesn't show all list items (<li>) from the menu

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm working on a website, I have implemented the inverted navbar from bootstrap taken from here :

https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

I haven't modified it, but when its resized to a smaller window in computer browser, or when viewed on a mobile phone, when you clicked the "3 bars icon" for expanding the menu it's not showing all of the menu buttons (

).

I have tried to change the CSS but without any luck.

What is it that I should look for to change, or why is it not showing all items from the menu?

This is the website itself: https:/dh-automotive.com

Comment: Post a jsfiddle of the navbar

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tz7t05rd/     it seems to work there , the HTML part is inside other div's so one of them is probally causing it not to display correctly.  I will look myself tomorrow , and will post a report here of my actions and results.  Thank you

Comment: Hello , so i have looked and there is only 1 css file used a part from the bootstrap ones , its a standard style.css , i have modified previous fiddle and added the entire style.css content underneath the bootstrap.(its quite long and minified as well).  https://jsfiddle.net/tz7t05rd/   when runned its giving the issue i have that i want to fix which is when collapsed and clicked to open , not all menu items are showing. I really appreciate whoever is putting his time into helping me out i really do ! Kind regards

Comment: No body has an idea or a suggestion ? Kind regards

Comment: Will try to help tonight or tomorrow, at work atm and busy recently, sry

Comment: No sorry needed i really appreciate anyone helping me out in any way ! I wish you best of luck at work ! Im trying to mod things arround in the style since i think the issue relies in there but no luck till now. Kind regards

Comment: So i have seen that in the style.css there is also some .nav classes and those are probally overriding or preventing the default bootsrap.css nav's . I am attempting to change things but still can't figure it out till now... Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find this in your style.css file:

```
.nav {
    width: 90%;
    float: right;
    max-height: 65px;
    min-width: 680px
 }
```

remove `max-heigh`t and `min-width` lines.

Overall, your CSS is incredibly messy, how did you manage to get it to this state? What are you using to build this website?

Comment: Thank you this indeed enabled me to see all items on in the menu.          Yes it is indeed verry messy , i added things seperately like menu's , and other css/js things to try out , but i lost track of what i use and what i don't. In other words i have been neglecting certain things (im new to html/css/js) and this got me where i am. Any idea how i would go to set all menu items underneath each other when the menu bars is clicked ? I want to thank you for your time you have putted in i really apreciate it Varin !

Comment: No problem. To be honest, I'd suggest first cleaning it all up. There is a lot of styles that are not needed at all. Strip it all down to bare minimum. Also, your images are HUGE!!! it makes the website load far too long. Reduce their size to what they appear on the website - around 900x600?? Save them as .png and put them through this tool: https://tinypng.com/

Also I can help you bit more but I don't understand what you mean by this: 

`Any idea how i would go to set all menu items underneath each other when the menu bars is clicked ?`

How do they show up now?

Comment: OK, I just visited your website, I'll have a look after work. Try deleting the whole `.nav` style I mentioned in my answer in your stylesheet and see what happens.

Comment: alright first im gonna try deleting the .nav style and see where it takes me. After that i will decrease the size of all the images (thanks to your kind help and advice ! )  and afterwards i will go and check which css/js aren't used and remove them. Iv'e already started cleaning up the html as well as making things more readable and commented.  I really thank you for your kind help i really mean it !

Comment: So i have played arround with the nav classes in the style.css , i have removed this part from it and each menuitem is now below eachother : `code` .nav li{border-left:0.5px solid rgba(100,32,32,1);border-right:0.5px solid rgba(100,32,32,1);width:14.333%;display:inline-block}   I also removed double content like css/js that was in each language version (overkill) i also minified every image's size with the link you gave me (now bookmarked) and next i am gonna go through each css file and see which is udes and which isn't and remove the unused ones. Same for the classes that arent used.

Comment: Edit for the above , in the css code i removed the "Display: inline-block;" for the menu items to show one below another. I am sorry for the unreadable code i don't know how to display code [php][/php] didn't worked ...

Comment: I have tryed multiple things,i am now only using bootsrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css ,i have tryed 3 different approaches but none worked **Option 1 :**  nav.nav-center{margin:0;float:none} .navbar-inner{ text-align:center}
 **Option 2 :**  .navbar.center .navbar-inner{text-align: center}.navbar.center .navbar-inner .nav{display:inline-block;float:none}
**Option 3 :**.navbar.center .navbar-inner{text-align: center}.navbar-nav {width:100%;text-align:center; > li {float: none;display: inline-block} }

Comment: What can i do to align the list items in the center when the menu isn't collapsed ? Kind regards !

Comment: Anyone any idea i still have issues to get the menu items centered in the middle ? Thank you !

Comment: Should i create another thread for this ? Im sure it might be something i am overlooking , i still am searching for a fix. I modified it in the debugger from the browser , i go to the css and change it but it doesn't take effect , its minified css so maybe that is causing it not to work idk ... Kind regards